# Previous data still present after $state.go() in Ionic Framework with Crosswalk

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

why is it after I fill up the necessary inputs then send to my server after sending I redirect user to some other page. When a user went back to that page, the info he filled still present in there. How can I fix this? It seems the info I filled is cached when in fact I didn't use such technology in my application. How can I clear the input data done before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the latest ionic release (v1.0.0-beta.14) they introduced view caching. See [IonView docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionView/) for more infos on that.

You could deactivate caching in for your route like this

```
.state('your.state', {
                url: '/your/url',
                cache: false,
                views: {
                    // ...
                }
            })
```

or directly in your view

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
```

See [ionNavView docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionNavView/)

Or you might even want to disable cache globally for testing:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

Comment: Is this applicable on the main html ? I want to put it on <ion-nav-view> so all other html inherit this.

Comment: not sure if I get you question? The first is used per-route in app.js, the second approach can be used for each <ion-view> directive. The 3rd approach would disable cache globally.

Comment: `<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">` works for me. I think i should use this globally using your third approach cause I might need to add new page and forgot to disable cache-view. Thanks!